# Proof assistant formalizations of Finite Model Theory

Tags: lo.logic, descriptive-complexity, finite-model-theory, proof-assistants

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a formalization (even limited) of any part of finite model theory in any of the major proof assistants. (I'm most familiar with Coq, but Isabelle, Agda, etc. would acceptable.)

Especially of interest would be any of the results in [descriptive complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory).